# Get relating order id on product stock change when order placed

Tags: woocommerce

I am developing stock status log feature to collect data of all products stock changes. I am using "woocommerce_product_set_stock" hook to write changes to custom database table. One big issue is that I cannot find out how to get related order to stock change when someone has placed a new order. When stock change is based on order cancel/refund I can get the order id from $_SERVER info but when placed a new order via checkout, there's nothing related to order id.

Customer requires order id information on stock change log so any hints, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When order cancelled or pending WooCommerce called this `wc_reduce_stock_levels` and `wc_increase_stock_levels` function to handle stock quantity.

You can use `woocommerce_reduce_order_stock` and `woocommerce_restore_order_stock` to write changes to your custom database table

```
function update_in_custom_table( $order ){
    
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    // We need an order, and a store with stock management to continue.
    if ( ! $order || 'yes' !== get_option( 'woocommerce_manage_stock' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Loop over all items.
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        
        if ( ! $item->is_type( 'line_item' ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $product = $item->get_product();
        
        if ( ! $product || ! $product->managing_stock() ) {
            continue;
        }

        $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();

    }

}   

add_action( 'woocommerce_reduce_order_stock', 'update_in_custom_table', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_restore_order_stock', 'update_in_custom_table', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Yes thank you very much! Was a busy day and just got my tests ready so this seems to work as expected. Much appreciate your help!

Comment: I already tried to upvote but: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."